# Forming new array of objects and getting count of similar values

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to form new array of objects using the old array object data. I want to get the average count of success and failure values.

```
//Old array of objects

[{
  "id": "1",
  "month": "MAR",
  "description": "success",
  "count": "100"
}, {
  "id": "2",
  "month": "APRIL",
  "description": "success",
  "count": "110"
}, {
  "id": "3",
  "month": "MAR",
  "description": "failed",
  "count": "50"
}, {
  "id": "4",
  "month": "MAR",
  "description": "failed",
  "count": "20"
}, {
  "id": "5",
  "month": "APRIL",
  "description": "success",
  "count": "100"
}, {
  "id": "6",
  "month": "APRIL",
  "description": "failed",
  "count": "80"
},
{
   "id": "7",
   "month": "MAR",
   "description": "success",
   "count": "300"
},
 {
   "id": "8",
   "month": "APRIL",
   "description": "failed",
   "count": "40"
}
]
```

New array of objects to get average value of success and failed in each month

```
//new array of objects
[{
"month":"MAR",
"success":200        // 100+300/2
"failed":35          // 50+20/2
},
{
"month":"APRIL",
"success":105        // 100+110/2
"failed":60          // 40+80/2  
}]
```

I have tried to get unique month and count of data, but I am not able to form the exact expected output. Any help will be really appreciated.

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/toj722h0/1/)

Comment: Please study up on the meaning of the term "JSON". In terms of your problem itself. the starting point would be to "group by" month, so do a google for "group by javascript". That will give you an array of objects for each month, then you can look at all of them and calculate the average success and failure numbers. Good luck!

Comment: ... and read the usage description of the `json` tag.

Comment: @torazaburo Thanks.

Comment: @ torazaburo;@trincot Any specific reason for downvote. It will be more helpful if you guys can provide me with some useful links

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you could do it with ES6, in a *functional programming* style:

```js
function summary(data) {
    return Array.from(new Set(data.map(o => o.month)), month =>  
        ["failed", "success"].reduce( (acc, description) => {
            const match = acc[1].filter(o => o.description == description)
                                .map(o => +o.count);
            acc[0][description] = match.length 
                               && match.reduce((a,b) => a+b)/match.length;
            return acc;
        }, [{ month }, data.filter(o => o.month == month)] )[0]
    );
}

const data = [{
  "id": "1",
  "month": "MAR",
  "description": "success",
  "count": "100"
}, {
  "id": "2",
  "month": "APRIL",
  "description": "success",
  "count": "110"
}, {
  "id": "3",
  "month": "MAR",
  "description": "failed",
  "count": "50"
}, {
  "id": "4",
  "month": "MAR",
  "description": "failed",
  "count": "20"
}, {
  "id": "5",
  "month": "APRIL",
  "description": "success",
  "count": "100"
}, {
  "id": "6",
  "month": "APRIL",
  "description": "failed",
  "count": "80"
}, {
   "id": "7",
   "month": "MAR",
   "description": "success",
   "count": "300"
}, {
   "id": "8",
   "month": "APRIL",
   "description": "failed",
   "count": "40"
}];

const result = summary(data);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is what I was exactly looking for

Answer (score 1):

Vanilla old-style Javascript approach:

```js
var list = [{
  "id": "1",
  "month": "MAR",
  "description": "success",
  "count": "100"
}, {
  "id": "2",
  "month": "APRIL",
  "description": "success",
  "count": "110"
}, {
  "id": "3",
  "month": "MAR",
  "description": "failed",
  "count": "50"
}, {
  "id": "4",
  "month": "MAR",
  "description": "failed",
  "count": "20"
}, {
  "id": "5",
  "month": "APRIL",
  "description": "success",
  "count": "100"
}, {
  "id": "6",
  "month": "APRIL",
  "description": "failed",
  "count": "80"
},
{
   "id": "7",
   "month": "MAR",
   "description": "success",
   "count": "300"
},
 {
   "id": "8",
   "month": "APRIL",
   "description": "failed",
   "count": "40"
}
];

var d = {};

for (var i=0,l; l = list[i]; i++) {
 if (!d[l.month]) d[l.month] = {failed:0, fcount:0, success:0, scount:0};

  if (l.description == 'failed') {
   var c = d[l.month].fcount;
   d[l.month].fcount++;
    d[l.month].failed = d[l.month].failed * c / (c + 1) + l.count / (c + 1);
  } else if (l.description == 'success') {
   var c = d[l.month].scount;
   d[l.month].scount++;
    d[l.month].success = d[l.month].success * c / (c + 1) + l.count / (c + 1);
  }
}
console.log(d);
```